# MySQL "SELECT INTO OUTFILE" fails with CIFS-mounted volume

Tags: mysql, backup, samba, cifs

`SELECT INTO OUTFILE` fails for a CIFS-mounted directory (`/mnt/backup/test`) but works for a normal directory (`/tmp/tests`).

```
mysql> select * from mytable into outfile '/tmp/tests/mytable.txt';
Query OK, 3723 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable into outfile '/mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt' (Errcode: 2)
```

The `mysql` user has no problem writing to `/mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt` :

```
root:~# su - -s /bin/bash mysql
mysql:~$ touch /mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt
mysql:~$ ls -l /mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2009-11-16 10:48 /mnt/backup/test/mytable.txt
```

The CIFS directory `/mnt/backup` is mounted with : `rw,noperm,user=****,password=****`

Since the `-T` option of `mysqldump` makes use of it, **what options** (Mysql/CIFS) **are needed** for `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` to work **with** my **CIFS**-mounted directory ?

**Update:**

Interestingly, an `strace` of the `mysqld` process did indeed reveal a access control failure as Michael suggested. But I still don't know **why**. A simple Perl script launched as `mysql` calls the same syscall with no problem.

Extract of mysqld strace

```
open("/mnt/backup/tests/bugs.1.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) 
        = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Extract of perl strace

```
open("/mnt/backup/tests/bugs.32064.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
```

Note that the directory `/mnt/backup/tests` was emptied before each run.

Comment: In the interest of troubleshooting does redirecting the std out to a file on that drive work? i.e.
    mysqldump > /mnt/backup/test/outfile.sql work?

Comment: Yes. Actually that's how I do it right now.

Comment: Ok, now I am seriously stumped.  Sounds like su - isn't faithfully emulating the environment, possible because of Michael's suggestion about the - needing to be the last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor).

Adding `/mnt/backup/** w` to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and restarting it (`/etc/init.d/apparmor restart`) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error might mean one of two things, the file might already exist or it is in fact a permissions problem (in spite of your example showing it isn't a permission problem, I believe it actually is).

Additionally, when you run 'su' with the '-' option to simulate their environment, you need to specify that as the last option to su.

Comment: `touch` works the same with `su -s /bin/bash mysql -`